# Changing a signal's DC offset before amplifiter and ADC

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, bias

I'm trying to feed an audio signal which has around 5v DC bias to an amplifier and then an ADC. the final signal should have 2.5v DC bias. i've mixed things i've learned off forums but i'm still not getting the desired result. i don't have an oscilloscope to check but when the samples are played back in android, the volume is too low so i'm guessing the DC bias is not set up correctly.

any input is appreciated
[image: Schematic]

the output from stage 1 is biased at exactly 2.5v while the final output is biased at 3.68Volt!

## **EDITS**

- C8 is 1uF in the actual soldered circuit
- the output from stage 1 is biased at exactly 2.5v while the final output is biased at 3.68Volt!

Comment: Your bias setup looks OK and you have lots of gain. Are your OpAmps capable of rail-to-rail output?

Comment: What is your Vcc? If you want to check the DC bias on the input to the ADC, make sure no signal is going into your circuit and put a volt meter set to VDC across c6

Comment: You don't need to have an oscilloscope to confirm output bias - just measure output voltage using any multi-meter or voltmeter without any input signal or input shorted to ground - output should be exactly 2,5V.

Comment: @user1582568 i just checked and no it doesn't provide rail to rail output. i'm using LM324 but since this is the exact op-amp used in AVR335 for voice recording purposes, i didn't think there would be a problem.

Comment: @laptop2d VCC is 5v. i feel stupid for not checking it with volt-meter. updating the question.

Comment: Does the output DC voltage vary as you adjust the gain pot? Could be you have leakage in C2 combined with a small offset voltage from stage 1, This would give a large offset when the pot was set to high gain. If the OpAmp powered from 5V?

Comment: Is the output of AMPA pin 1 at 3.68V? If that point is at 2.5V, then the specific ADC identification would be useful.

Comment: @user1582568 no it's a steady 3.71v at pin 1 even when the pot is at ~10 Ohms

Comment: @PeterSmith no unfortunately it's the circuit not the ADC

Comment: @lustful-rat first output is exactly 2.5v but the second one is higher than it should be

Comment: The ADC should read midscale i.e. 512 for a ten bit when you have no input. Record the ADC to whatever RAM you have and dump the numbers into Excel, graph. Presto, instant scope!. You will then be able to see the dynamics, clipping etc.

Comment: @M47 rather update question with comment and your response to it than respond to comments in comments.

Comment: Do you get the same voltage each side of R13?

Comment: Also look for for Oscilloscope and 'sound analyzer' on playstore, iStore and sourceforge - sufficient for these needs.

Comment: @user1582568 its 3.71 at the pin, 3.68 after the low-pass filter. if all else fails is there any work around to this ?

Comment: Maybe C2 is damaged or leaky. If you disconnect "stage 2 input" does the output change to 2.5V?

Comment: R13 should go down a lot, you want a low impedance feed to the ADC.

Comment: Put a 100nF or bigger over R4 to smooth the virtual earth.

Comment: If disconnecting C2 makes not difference try another OpAmp

Comment: @ChrisR will add the 100nF capacitor, thanks. R13 combined with C6 creates a low-pass filter with 2.8kHz cutoff frequency which is needed to prevent aliasing later on when the samples are played back

Comment: @SpehroPefhany will be hard since its on a pcb but decent idea. thanks

Comment: If you cannot remove C2, can you place you volt meter across R5? This will tell you if there is leakage. Put it on mV range is possible. It should read very close to 0mV.

Comment: I'm using ARM ADC, they vary from 47K down to 5K input impedance, depending on sampling time. Your filter should have probably 10% of that else it won't charge the sampling cap.

Comment: Do you really need 1000* voltage gain? what are the input signal levels? try ampA at unity to 5* gain, for 100mV input. Balance the gain between the amps. Set Gain to sq root of overall gain requirement.

Comment: Have you decoupled the Opamp supplies with 4uF // 100nF?

Comment: The C6 capacitor connection is very weird as you obviously don't want to have a low-pass filter formed by the R13 and C6 components (cut-off frequency is at about 2.8 kHz). You should instead put the 12k resistor to ground and directly connect the op-amp output to the ADC.

Comment: @ChrisR i don't really have a choice because it is absolutely needed. if i don't use it an annoying noise is added to the sound. its either the harmonics caused by aliasing or some noise i don't know. either way the filter is working

Comment: at the frequency i'm working with i can only get 55x gain from the second stage. the potentiometer is just there in case i want to attenuate the signal a bit

Comment: I think what @lucas92 and I are saying is to move the LP filter between stage 1 and 2, you can then have very high impedances, Q and small components. Like lukas92, I also put OPAMP out directly to ADC, as do ST in their mixed designs.

Comment: I an upvoting @user1582568 (first post), I recall having a problem feeding audio and not having rail to rail opamps. I saw your comment. Could you breadboard the mods from all the authors above and retest?

Comment: @ChrisR ah didn't catch that. thank you. the circuit is working now although not perfect. i can't increase the gain too much or else i get a deafening noise. could be because i haven't decoupled the supplies like you said (+ i'm using a DC-DC voltage converter to get my VCC). and yes, LM324 doesn't provide rail to rail output, but it'll do for now. the project is due in less than two weeks and i still have a lot of bugs to fix. thanks again for all the help

Comment: You've seen it before when dealing digital - decouple, when dealing analog - decouple, when dealing hybrid - double decouple.

Comment: @user1582568 the chip('s 2nd stage) was faulty, changing it fixed the problem. could you post it as the answer ?

Comment: In the 3 volt realm, everyone seems to have gone rail to rail and used  3V VCC. Integrate the noise out digitally after the adc - oversample and average. You may find the noise is the sampling cap feeding back to C6, 12k impedance cant handle the glitches. Set filter to 470nF/120R for same time constant.

Comment: @ChrisR don't know if i can oversample since the microcontroller is busy starting ADC conversions and sending them as well as receiving samples from the other side and playing them over PWM. will try the filter with less impedance though. great advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output voltage is not at the correct DC level, but the DC bias is correct, change the amplifier. There is lots of other good advide here, particularly @ChrisR decoupling comments. Another point to note is the the virtual earth connections (ive Opamp inputs) are very sensitive to capacative pickup, so ensure that they are routed close to the amp and do not do near potentially noisy signals.